# Allow touch events to pass through an overlaying Image in Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, service, mobile-application, android-windowmanager

In my project, when the service class gets called, it overlays an Image on top of the mobile screen. Foreground service is used to continuously keep the image on top of the mobile screen even when my app gets closed.

The only issue left to resolve here is that:
This overlaying image is not allowing the touch events to pass through the image to the mobile screen and the issue is only occurring on **Android 11 and 12**. I have tested the code on Android 6,10 and 13. it is working fine.

How can I modify this code so that touch events can be allowed to pass through the overlaying image? I have also successfully asked the run-time permission for 'Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION' to overlay my image on top of mobile screen

So this is the function that overlays the image on top of my mobile screen. It is working fine on different versions of Android but the issue persists only on Android 11 and 12. How can I make the touch pass through the image on android 11 and 12?

```
   private fun showImageOverlay(imageUri: Uri) {
        removeImageOverlay()

        val type: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        }

        val flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE

        val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            type,
            flags,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        val overlayView = ImageView(this).apply {
            // Use Glide to load and set the image
            Glide.with(this@BrokenServiceClass)
                .load(imageUri)
                .into(this)
        }

        val touchInterceptor = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ -> // Pass touch events to the underlying elements
            false
        }

        overlayView.setOnTouchListener(touchInterceptor)

        windowManager?.addView(overlayView, layoutParams)

        overlayView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
                // The overlay view is attached to the window
            }

            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) {
                // The overlay view is detached from the window
                removeImageOverlay()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: "I have tested the code on Android 6,10 and 13. it is working fine." -- I certainly hope not. What you are describing is malware executing a tapjacking attack, and that has been blocked by the OS for over a decade.

Comment: @CommonsWare have you seen multiple apps that are available on the play store named something like BrokenWallpaper. I am trying to achieve that simple functionality in my project where a cracked picture will be simply overlayed on a mobile screen through a service class.
If this is not the correct approach can you guide me on how can i achieve this functionality in my code?

Comment: @CommonsWare there are auto clickers on the playstore that allow click through for legit reasons, and they work on all android versions, so what this person is trying to do is possible and most likely legit. I see you comment a lot about malware, which isn't always the case.